# How to enable fluentd pluggins

Tags: java, multiline, fluentd

I am using EFK.

Could someone help here on how to enable `fluentd` plugins.

I have installed the following 3 plugins as part of my work.

```
gem install fluent-plugin-concat
gem install fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions
gem install fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions-with-error
gem install fluent-plugin-record-modifier
```

And I am seeing the list of gems installed here:

```
opsmxuser@opsmx-ind-setup:~/docker-compose-efk$ fluent-gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
.
.
fluent-plugin-concat (2.4.0)
fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions (0.0.12)
fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions-with-error (0.0.3)
fluent-plugin-record-modifier (2.0.1)
fluentd (1.6.2, 0.14.25)
.
.
```

But these 3 plugins are not enabled. When we are using these configurations into `fluent.conf` file getting following error messages into `fluentd` container logs.

> 2019-08-05 12:34:55 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
> 2019-08-05 12:34:55 +0000 [error]: config error file="/etc/fluent/fluent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Unknown filter plugin 'concat'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"

> 2019-08-02 12:46:23 +0000 [error]: config error file="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Unknown output plugin 'detect_exceptions'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"

> 2019-08-05 12:34:55 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
> 2019-08-05 12:34:55 +0000 [error]: config error file="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Unknown filter plugin 'record_modifier'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"

Answer (score 0):

Add to fluentd config @type copy directive. 
Example below:

```
    <match **>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type exec
    @id load2clickhouse
    command bash /usr/local/bin/insert_ch.sh {{ template "fluentdInsertTable" $ }}
    format json
    <buffer>
      @type memory
      chunk_limit_size 32m
      queue_limit_length 32
      flush_at_shutdown true
      flush_interval 15s
      flush_thread_count 4
    </buffer>
  </store>
  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host ip
    port 5044
    logstash_format true
</store>
</match>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem today.

I follow the fluent github issue, build a image with plugin in it

[build your own image](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-docker-image#how-to-build-your-own-image)

it works for me